# RTL SlideShow For React native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, slideshow, rtl-language

i need to RTL react native slideshow.
testing react native snap carousel but this library have error in RTL.

i testing bellow Library:
react-native-swiper
react native snap carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react-native-swiper : 
You can use style and flexDirection:'row-reverse' in .
Also if use autoPlay you can set autoplayDirection={false}

Comment: swipe won't work correctly with this approach